# Java command terminal

Tags: java

Alright so i am trying to run my java file but it's not doing what I want it to from terminal.

I have a main directory called packageTester.

packageTester contains src and bin

src has packageA packageB

pacakgeA has HelloA.java 
packageB has HelloB.java

bin has my class files so

bin has packageA packageB

pacakgeA has HelloA.class 
packageB has HelloB.class

To compile the files I used the following command when I was in the pacakageTester directory:
   javac -d bin -sourcepath source src/package*/* , which works !

Now how do I run HelloB.class which contains the main method and has an object of HelloA.

I thought when at the packageTester directory, I can do:
       java bin/packageB/HelloB 
but that does not work because it cannot seem to find the .class file.
HELP will be greatly appreciated to figure out how to execute the file correctly

Comment: `java packageB.HelloB` ?

Comment: This works if I cd into the bin folder: java packageB/HelloB

But why does it not work if I am not in the packageTester directory?
So:
java bin/packageB/HelloB  ?

Comment: Which command do you use to execute your classes? Can you post the exception?

Comment: Hey Julian. Just answered that 1 post above. 

Abhinavs-MacBook-Pro:packageTester tactician$ java bin/packageB/HelloB

Error: Could not find or load main class bin.packageB.HelloB

Abhinavs-MacBook-Pro:packageTester tactician$ 

That is from the packageTester directory; however it works if i am in the bin directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of `bin` should be in your classpath in order for `packageB.HelloB` to be found as `packageB/HelloB.class` while parsing the classpath.

The easiest way to do so is to change directory to `bin` and execute `java packageB.HelloB` from there.

Alternatively, you can execute `java -cp bin packageB.HelloB` from your `packageTester` directory, or from somewhere else if you replace `bin` by an absolute path.

Comment: Ty sir ! I was trying to find a way to just simply stay in the packageTester and compile/run the files from there. Thanks !

Comment: @AbhinavRana You're welcome ! Please accept the answer if it fully solved your problem.